# Usage of the boolean java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object o) method. Determining which two objects are equal

Tags: java

I am using the "boolean java.util.ArrayList.contains(Object o)" method to find a specific object in a list (of type ArrayList).

The method description in under the following link,
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
states the following,
*"Returns true if this list contains the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null : o.equals(e))."*

So what I want to do is to override/redefine the "equals()" method in a class called Person. Then in Another class called, "MyStorage" I want to populate a list with Person type objects. After this I would like to use the "contains()" method to find a Person object that has the same prio number as the Person object that I pass as the argument to contains method. I DON'T want the contains method to return true if and only if two references x and y refer to the same object. Instead I want the contains method to return true if x and y have the same prio numbers. So that is why I have overridden the equals method in the Person class. The problem is that contains seem to check equality based on reference and not on prio number.

Here follows my test code...

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyStorage<E> extends ArrayList<E> {

    public static void main(String [ ] args)
    {
        MyStorage<Person> list = new MyStorage<Person>();
        Person p1 = new Person(1);
        list.add(p1);
        Person p2 = new Person(2);
        list.add(p2);
        list.add(new Person(3));

                // This test code shows that the overridden equals method in class Person
                // is not used by contains method. Right?
        p1.setPrio(10);
        if(list.contains(p1))
            System.out.print("Found!");

    }

    public MyStorage(){
        super();
    }

//  @Override
//  public boolean contains(Object o){
//      Iterator<E> itr = super.iterator();
//      while(itr.hasNext()){
//          System.out.print("Works!");
//      }
//      return false;
//  }

}


// And the Person class....
public class Person {

    private int prio;

    public Person(int prio){
        this.prio = prio;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o){

        if(o instanceof Person){
            Person p = (Person) o;
            if(this.prio == p.prio)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }else{
            return false;
        }   
    }

    public void setPrio(int prio){
        this.prio = prio;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, it does use the overriden `equals()`. Why do you think it doesn't? Also, to determine which element is equal to the given one you can use [`indexOf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#indexOf(java.lang.Object))

Comment: @PAT When you debugging, it didn't go to your `equals` method ?

Comment: This question doesn't really make sense. Your `equals` implementation compares `Person`s based on the `prio` field, which is set by the constructor. `new Person(4)` isn't contained by the list because no `Person` instance in the list has a `prio` of `4`.

Comment: @RongNK
No, it did not. 
When I write the following test lines,
p1.setPrio(10);
        if(list.contains(new Person(p1)))
            System.out.print("Found!");

It says it found the object. But in my equals method I have stated that two equal objects must have the same prio number.

Comment: @PAT: the code in your comment won't even compile, because you have no such constructor. Also, use backticks `\`` in the comments to mark code.

Comment: @PAT I don't see any constructor in your Person class that accept a Person as parameter.

Comment: @Paul Bellora right, @PAT try with `if(list.contains(new Person(2)))`.

Comment: If you uncomment `//p1.setPrio(4);`, it works fine: http://ideone.com/ecNtCj - voting to close.

Comment: @RongNK
When I  try, 
if(list.contains(new Person(2)))

...it finds the object. But I am expecting it to find it using that test code.

Comment: @PAT see Paul Bellora's comment, you just uncomment to `p1.setPrio(4);`

Comment: @PAT: As said above: Use backticks `\`` to mark code in a comment. What test code are you talking about?

Comment: I have updated my example code above.

Comment: @PAT: Is it printing `Found!` and you think it shouldn't because you changed the `prio` from `p1` after inserting it into the list?

Comment: @jlordo Thanks for the advice, will use the backsticks `.

Comment: @jlordo hehe..I Think you are on to something....
Yes, you have understood the problem I have.

Comment: @PAT: You're not adding the person to the list, you are adding a reference to that person to the list. So `p1.setPrio(10);` changes `p1`, but it's still the same object. The reference in the list still points to that same object as `p1` does. Understand the problem?

Comment: @PAT: For the future: If you have a question like this. Always describe the behavior you expect and the behavior you get. This would have avoided much confusion for us.

Comment: @jlordo Sorry I will do this in the future.

Comment: I have accepted an answer made by Amir Pashazadeh. Would like to also thank everyone else for your feedback and time spent trying to find my mistake. Having corrected my mistake (test code snippet) I feel that I have understood how I can change how the contians method decide which two objects are equal. There are other ways to do this as well, but I wanted to try this one particular.

Comment: @jlordo I think you also understood my error. Thank you for your insight and advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By calling `p1.setPrio(10);` you are changing `prio` in `p1`, the exact instance in the storage, so it is obvious that `equals()` should return `true`, because you are comparing an instance with itself.

Comment: Hi Amir Pashazadeh, you're absolutly correct! I took a break from my problem and when I came back I realized my dumb mistake. I used a really bad test code snippet. The following snippet,

`p1.setPrio(10);
 if(list.contains(p1))
 System.out.print("Found!");`

updated the reference p1 that I already had inserted into the list then I passed the very same reference to search for itself in the list...lol yeees of course it will always return true! Programming make one humble. :-)

Comment: ....So what I did instead was to create the following test snippet,

`p1.setPrio(10);
Person p4 = new Person(10);
if(list.contains(p4))
System.out.print("Found!");
else
System.out.print("Not Found!");`

And it worked exactly as intended. So what I did was to create a new seperate object reference and gave it the same prio number as p1 that already existed in the list.  Thank you Amir. :-)